# How to explain the concept of "instance" to the average user

Tags: usability, instance, user-experience

I am creating an application where users can create cards and decks of cards.

One thing they can do is create a card and share an instance of it among decks. So if they modify this card all the instances in all the decks will be changed too. This is very useful in my app however it might surprise users so I want to explain this in a simple way.

How would you go about explaining that? As programmers we all know what instances are, but are regular users familiar with the concept? Should I use the word "instance" at all or is there an equivalent word with which users would be more familiar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think "instance" is a completely terrible term to use, but maybe an alternate way to explain it is something like:

> Every card that you create is unique.  No matter how many decks you add your
>   card to, only one actual copy exists.  Modifying the card in any one
>   deck will cause the same updates to automatically appear in every
>   other deck that includes the same card.

...or some such less verbose variation.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good way to look it. I will use a variation of your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can invent some word for such cards. And explain in short, that changing properties of 'MAdeCards' will be visible everywhere. And avoid the word 'instance'.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at it the other way, and call the instances just 'cards'. The 'template' or 'class' could then be called a 'card type'.

Answer (score 0):

What about telling them about the hierarchical part of OOP? A card has a father and a mother for it's left and right pointer. A card can have children (again for it's left and right pointer). It's most likely that every children of a master card share his attributes. An outstanding attribute of the master card is the unique attribute. If the master card is modified in way all it's children gets modified in the same way without any delay?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to buy a new mobile phone (cell phone). Or a car.

That's a class:

- hypothetical at the moment
- don't have it yet to use
- no state (eg no battery to have a charge or don't know what fuel will be in the tank)

I've bought a new Samsumg or Audi. That's an Instance.

- I can play with it ("Instantiated")
- I can measure things eg battery charge etc ("State")

Non-techie folk don't care about our day to day concepts so don't even use "Instance" maybe

In the real world, one card would not be in several decks, let alone all decks. At first glance, your model doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Imagine for instance a game of Magic The Gathering where you can create your own cards and decks. You might want to create a deck for fun, one for competition, an experimental one, etc. and add your custom cards to all these decks. Now when you change something to your card, for example the description, you will want the card to be updated in all your decks. That's where the concept of instance is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Instance can be replaced by 'Edit Master Card' and also you can have text assistance next to the link / button "Note: The modification would reflect in all of your existing decks". Hope you can rephrase the content how the way the 'target user' wants. You need to check with the target users with the button and help text whether this information is well receive by them, or else ask them suggestion in what way they get it easier to rephrase it then consolidate the response and conclude.